# Keep a fluid max number of posts on site

Tags: posts, functions

I'm trying to figure out how to set the max number of posts allowed across the site, but keep it fluid by sending old posts to the bin when a new post is over the limit.

(I'm trying to stop the database being flooded and slowing the whole site down)

*For example*: I have a jobs board that will be importing large amounts of posts fairly regularly, but I only want a maximum of 1000 posts on the site. Old posts are obselete so as soon as someone adds post number 1001 the oldest post would be moved to the bin.

I've found a snippet that limits the number of non-admin posts:

```
    add_action("load-post-new.php","limit_user_by_post_count");
function limit_user_by_post_count(){
    $user = get_current_user_id();
    if (!current_user_can( 'manage_options')) { 
        //not an admin - so impose the limit
        $user_post_count = count_user_posts($user);
        if($user_post_count>=10)
            header("Location: /wp-admin/edit.php");
    }
}
```

But it does so by redirecting the user to the all posts page (& stopping them from posting anything new) and I'm not really well versed enough to modify it to send the oldest post to the bin?

Comment: You could either remove old posts while importing new posts, or setup a cron job to clean up the database once a day/week. The idea is to setup a count query using $wpdb, get the total count of posts for a specific post type, and if the count is greater than 1000, get the difference, and update the post status to "trash". That would still keep those posts in the database, but you could let wordpress handle the trash can clean up by setting the trash days limit. Link -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea but before we go into details, here are **VERY VERY IMPORTANT** notes

### NOTE: READ THIS FIRST

- Take a database back up before running this code. It is advisable to run this on a local install first for testing purposes.
- Note on [`wp_trash_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trash_post), from the codex

  > If trash is disabled, the post or page is permanently deleted.
- I have tested the code, and it works. You can however make changes to it to suite your needs. As it stands, the code should only delete posts when a new post is published

### WORKSFLOW

What we need to do is

- Run a custom function to delete posts when ever a new post is published. For this, we will use the `transition_post_status` hook. Just one note, this hook fires when a post is published, trashed, updated and untrashed. We will need to restrict our custom function to only run when a post is published. This line, `if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' )` will take care of that
- Use `get_posts()` to get all the published posts. You can adjust this to suite your needs. We only need the post ids, so this is what we will get. It makes the query really fast and does not eat up resources
- The returned array of posts from `get_posts()` needs to be counted, and if there are more than a 1000 posts, we need to get the post ids after the first thousand posts. we will use `array_slice` here
- We need to run `wp_trash_post` if we have more than 1000 posts to trash these posts. If you need to delete everything attached to the post as well, you can use `wp_delete_post` here instead of `wp_trash_post`. You can just uncomment this line, `wp_delete_post( $trash_post  );` in the code and comment this line out `wp_trash_post( $trash_post  );`. Do not run both at the same time

### PUTTING IT INTO CODE

The code is well commented as well, so it will be easy to follow. Just one note, you will need a minimum of PHP5.4+ installed on your server due to the use of new array syntax. Also note, closures needs a minimum of PHP5.3

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    // Run this only when a new post is publish to save on unnecessary waste of resources
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
    
        /*
         * Use get_posts() to count all the posts published, get only post ids to improve performance
         * This array of post ids will also be used to get the post ids of posts to be trashed
         */
        $total_posts = get_posts( ['posts_per_page' => -1, 'fields' => 'ids'] );
        // Count the amount of posts in the returned array from get_posts
        $count = count( $total_posts );
        
        // Run the following only if we have more than a thousand posts
        if ( $count > 1000 ) {
        
            // Get all post id after the first 1000 posts
            $set_to_trash = array_slice( $total_posts, 1000 );
            foreach ( $set_to_trash as $trash_post ) {
                // Use wp_trash_post to trash the posts 
                wp_trash_post( $trash_post  );
               // You can also use wp_delete_post here to delete everything attached to the post
               //wp_delete_post( $trash_post );
            }
            // Unset $trash_post for safety
            unset( $trash_post );
            
        }
        
    }
    
}, 10, 3 );
```

### TO CONCLUDE

You can set your installation to permanently delete trashed posts by adding the following line to `wp-config.php`

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 );
```

Just note, this will permanently delete posts and they cannot be recovered

Comment: Worked. I also added a 'post_type' array to get_posts() to reflect it on my custom post type.  my job board is now fluid! Thanks so much!

Comment: Perfect. Glad it worked. Enjoy :-)