# Limit Number of Custom Post Type Dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, database, wp-admin

new to Stackexchange , Apologies in advance ..

i have custom post type named Floorplans and i want to restrict them to total of 10 .. Means site admin can create up to 10 post types only ..

thanks in advance too.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress development. Do you mean that you want the admin to be able to publish only 10 **posts** under that post type?

Comment: You might want to post some example code so that potential respondents have a frame of reference. For example, the name of the CPT is "Floorplans" but is the slug actually "floorplans" or is it something else?  Maybe include the code you are using the declare the CPT.

Comment: I think there is a very good solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191198/keep-a-fluid-max-number-of-posts-on-site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to limit the number of "floorplan" posts a given user can publish? The [Limit Posts plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-posts/) can handle this for you.